# How to set an image as a RadioButton argument programmatically?

Tags: android, background, radio-button

I have a RadioGroup which consists of five RadioButtons. What I'd like to achieve is setting an image as a RadioButton argument. So far found this way:

```
radio0.setBackgroundResource(<drawable ID, int>);
```

but it gives something like this (descriptions "isSelected" added in an image editor):

[image: Background of RadioButton]

1. Is there any way to programmatically set background properties and move the image to the right?
2. Or maybe there is another way to set an image next to RadioButton instead of using it as a background image?

I'm interested only in programmatical solutions, as the RadioGroup is cleared up and filled again during loop work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me to figure out this issue.

Instead of the code line posted in the question I use this one now:

```
radio0.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, <drawable ID, int>, 0);
```

The third parameter corresponds to *android:drawableRight* XML parameter. More on this: [click](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Thanks to it a picture is set to the right of the RadioButton and finally it looks like it should.

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003981/how-to-put-an-image-to-the-right-of-a-radio-button-android